# Testing if all values in a numpy array are equal

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy one dimensional array `c` that is supposed to be filled with the contents of
`a + b`. I'm first executing `a + b` on a device using `PyOpenCL`.

I want to quickly determine the correctness of the result array `c` in python using `numpy` slicing.

This is what I currently have

```
def python_kernel(a, b, c):
    temp = a + b
    if temp[:] != c[:]:
        print "Error"
    else:
        print "Success!"
```

But I get the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

But it seems `a.any` or `a.all` will just determine whether the values aren't 0.

What should I do if I want to test if all of the scalers in the `numpy` array `temp` are equal to every value in the `numpy` array `c`?

Comment: `all_values_are_same = all(your_array[0] == your_array):`  What that does is return a list of boolean if each value equals the first value, and asserts all of them are true.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Why not just use [`numpy.array_equal(a1, a2)`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html)  from NumPy's functions?

Comment: You can check the source code of array_equal(), and because it call equal(), it also create the entire boolean vector.

Comment: I wonder why the API isn't `a1.array_equal(a2)`...

Answer (score 15):

[np.allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) is a good choice if `np.array` data type is floats. `np.array_equal` does not always work properly. For example:

```
import numpy as np
def get_weights_array(n_recs):
    step = - 0.5 / n_recs
    stop = 0.5
    return np.arange(1, stop, step)

a = get_weights_array(5)
b = np.array([1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6])
```

Result:

```
>>> a
array([ 1. ,  0.9,  0.8,  0.7,  0.6])
>>> b
array([ 1. ,  0.9,  0.8,  0.7,  0.6])
>>> np.array_equal(a, b)
False
>>> np.allclose(a, b)
True

>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:13:16) \n[GCC 4.7.2]'
>>> np.version.version
'1.6.2'
```

Comment: This was giving me a headache, good to know that `np.array_equal` bombs with floats. Thanks you!

Comment: Usual floating point precision errors. I wouldn't blame `array_equal` for working incorrectly here. It does what it is supposed to do. Any yes, `allclose` is the correct choice for what you intend to do.

Answer (score 7):

You would call `any` on the result of the comparison: `if np.any(a+b != c):` or equivalently `if np.all(a+b == c):`.  `a+b != c` creates an array of `dtype=bool`, and then `any` looks at that array to see if any member is `True`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> b = np.array([4,5,2])
>>> c = a+b
>>> c
array([5, 7, 5]) # <---- numeric, so any/all not useful
>>> a+b == c
array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool) # <---- BOOLEAN result, not numeric
>>> all(a+b == c)
True
```

Having said all that, though, [Amber's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100995/testing-if-all-values-in-a-numpy-array-are-equal/7101026#7101026) is probably faster since it doesn't have to create the whole boolean result array.