# scipy - construction of lattice which traps molecules in 2d dimension

Tags: python, scipy

this is a continuation of a previous stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038420/python-construction-of-lattice-which-traps-molecules-doesnt-work-right)

I want to do it in 2 dimensions.
I tried the following:

```
for i in range(pos):
    steps=0   #the steps that the particle does until it falls in  a trap
    in_pos = sc.random.randint(0, len(grid), 2)
    initial_trap=False
    while initial_trap==False:
        #the step of the particle can be one of this
        step=sc.array(random.choice([[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0]]))          
        # Check position for edges and fix if required

        if in_pos + step > sc.size(grid) - 1:
            in_pos = 0
        elif in_pos + step < 0:
            in_pos = sc.size(grid) - 1
        else:
            in_pos += step


        # Check if it's a trap in order to stop the loop

        if grid[in_pos] == 0:
            initial_trap = True

        # If it isn't a trap, continue
        steps+=1
    steps_count.append(steps)
return steps_count
```

I also tried :

```
in_pos_x =int(sc.random.randint(0, len(grid), 1)) #initial position of particle in x axis
in_pos_y =int(sc.random.randint(0, len(grid), 1)) #initial position of particle in y axis

if  in_pos_x + step > len(grid)- 1 and in_pos_y + step > len(grid)-1:
    in_pos_x = 0
    in_pos_y = 0
elif in_pos_x + step < 0 and in_pos_y + step < 0:
    in_pos_x = len(grid)- 1
    in_pos_y = len(grid)- 1
else:    in_pos_x += step
    in_pos_y += step

if grid[in_pos_x][in_pos_y] == 0:
    initial_trap = True
```

And last,i tried to work with lists, not arrays.

```
in_pos = (scipy.random.randint(0,len(grid),2)).tolist()
step=random.choice([[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0]])
```

but with no success either.
I am lost here!

---------------Error messages-----------------------------

If run the program it gives me:

'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()' at the line "if (in_pos + step) > sc.size(grid) - 1:"

If i use `if sc.any(in_pos + step) > sc.size(grid) - 1:` or `if sc.any(grid[in_pos]) == 0:` it runs but i used a `print(grid[in_pos])` and I figured that it doesn't change values at all! It doesn't get the value '0', so the loop never ends.

Comment: It would be better if you tell *what* is not working.

Comment: Nothing is working under the 'step=sc.array(random.choice([[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0]]))'

Comment: You can still do better. "Not working"=? Throws exception? In that case share the exception. Doesn't do what you intended? In that case share what it does and what you intended.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100995/testing-if-all-values-in-a-numpy-array-are-equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the comments, I think I understand where you are going.

I guess you are using periodic boundaries, but the check you are doing as below is wrong:

```
# Check position for edges and fix if requireD

if in_pos + step > sc.size(grid) - 1:
    in_pos = 0
elif in_pos + step < 0:
    in_pos = sc.size(grid) - 1
else:
    in_pos += step
```

`size` returns the total number of elements in an array. You need to check individual lengths (in `x` and `y` directions) of array. Here, `shape` is your friend. And you need to correct the index that goes beyond the limits, not all of them. `mod` operator `%` can be of use. So the above code can be simply re-written as:

```
# Move by step
in_pos += step
# Correct according to periodic boundaries
in_pos = in_pos % grid.shape    # or simply in_pos %= grid.shape
```

Second problem is the indexing of `grid`. Suffice it to say, the way you are doing is not what you want ([check the docs for details](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html)). For your simple case it can be re-written as:

```
if grid[in_pos[0], in_pos[1]] == 0:
    initial_trap = True
```

Comment: :Ok,i think its right.I will test it tomorrow.I just don't understand how the in_pos% grid.shape works..It is equivalent with "if in_pos + step > len(grid) - 1...."that i have above?If i wanted to apply it to 1dimension it would be "in_pos = in_pos % len(grid)? or len(grid)-1?But i still don't understand the modulo.

Comment: @George: Say you have a 3x3 grid. You are at [1,2] (that's end of the second row) and you want to go right ([+0,+1]). What you will have is [1,3], but that's out of bounds. So you need to come back from the left side (i.e. periodic boundary) and be at [1,0]. grid.shape gives you [3,3]. % with an array will give you mod with each corresponding element. So [1,3] % [3,3] == [1%3,3%3] == [1,0]. In general %n gives you something in [0,n-1], so that makes it useful in periodic stuff.

Comment: :Ok,thanks i understood that now.But ,it confuses me now abou the 1 dimension .The equivalent would be in_pos%=len(grid)-1 ? Thanks again!

Comment: @George: no need for -1, just in_pos%=len(grid) is enough.